# How to find the 3rd occurrence of a pattern on a line

Tags: regex, vim, alignment, tabular

Today I had to align a table at only the first multiple spaces on a line.

p.e.

```
<ScrollWheelDown>    move window     three lines     down  
<S-ScrollWheelDown>     move window    one page   down
<ScrollWheelUp>        move window      three lines up
<S-ScrollWheelUp>    move window   one page      up
```

I use Tabular plugin to align tables but I could not find a way how to find only the first occurrence of multiple spaces and do an align only there.

I don't know it either in VIM:
What will be the regex if I only want to find the 3rd occurrence of a pattern on a line?
Is the regex the same as using Tabular?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The regex would be:

```
/\(.\{-}\zsPATTERN\)\{3}
```

So if, for example, you want to change the 3rd 'foo' to 'bar' on the following line:

```
lorem ifoopsum foo lor foor ipsum foo dolor foo
       ^1      ^2      ^3         ^4        ^5
```

run:

```
s/\(.\{-}\zsfoo\)\{3}/bar/
```

to get:

```
lorem ifoopsum foo lor barr ipsum foo dolor foo
       ^1      ^2      ^3=bar     ^4        ^5
```

Comment: Very nice use of `\zs` inside a `\(...\)` block. I didn't know that when repeating zs, only the last one was taken into account. Of course `:help /\zs` states it.

Comment: Thanks Eelvex, I still have a little problem. The regex doesn't stop after it has found the 3rd 'foo'. It will change also the 6th 'foo' and the 9th 'foo'. How can i stop the regex after the 3rd 'foo'?

Comment: @Remonn: Just request start of line (`^`) at the beginning: `/^\(.\{-}...` but is this really necessary? `:s` without `g` at the end would only replace the first occurrence of your third pattern. :)

Comment: That was quit simple. Thank you.

Comment: An alternative syntax, using the `\v` modifier, is `s/\v(.{-}\zsfoo){3}/bar/` which may or may not offer improved readability, depending on your preference between regular escaping and `\v`.

Comment: it should be add `^` in the very begining of regex ( `^\(.\{-}\zsPATTERN\)\{3}` ), otherwise every 3rd "PATTERN" will be matched (i.e.: the 3rd, the 6th, the 9th, ...) . details: https://marslo.github.io/ibook/vim/tricky.html#matches-the-n-pattern

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it fits your needs, but you can search that way :

1. Place your cursor at the beginning line
2. Type <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> `pattern` <kbd>Return</kbd>

It place the cursor on the 3rd occurrence of the next matching line (highlighting all occurrences)

You can also macro :

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

then <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to go to the next line 3rd occurence

Comment: not exactly because it searches only in one line the 3rd occurrence and in other lines the first occurrence.

Comment: You can jump 3 by 3 with <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> also.

Comment: Maybe with a macro you can simplify the process. I suppose there is also a shortcut to go to beginning of next line but do not remember it.

Comment: (See also [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Answer (score 4):

For Google users (like me) that search just for: "regex nth occurrence". This will return position of last character of third 'foo' (you need to change `{3}` to your `n` and `foo` to your text):

```
length(regexp_replace('lorem ifoopsum foo lor foor1 ipsum foo dolor foo', '((?:.*?foo){3}).*$', '\1'))
```

This: `(?:.*?foo)` searches for anything followed by 'foo', then it is repeated 3 times `(?:.*?foo){3}`, then string from start to (including) 3rd repetition is captured, then rest of string is matched by `.*$`, then whole string is replaced by captured thing, and length of it is position of last character of 3rd 'foo'.

Comment: P.S. those 'vim' regexes, whatever they are, look awful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:Tabularize /^.\{-}\S\s\{2,}
```

Yes, Tabularize uses Vim's regex, so the example on Eelvex's answer should work.

Comment: to tabular the 2nd `,`, it should be `:Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs,\)\{2}/l1l0` ; or with `\v`: `:Tabularize /\v^(.{-}\zs,){2}/l1l0`. details: https://marslo.github.io/ibook/vim/plugins.html#align-with-the-n-pattern ; and https://marslo.github.io/ibook/vim/tricky.html#matches-the-n-pattern