# Ignoring a specific pattern (Regex)

Tags: regex

Text:

> Total amount due (inc. GST $7.68)    $84.55

Regex:

```
Total Amount.?\s*(?!\(inc\))?[^\$]*(\$\s?[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{1,})?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/YXr023/1

but it matches the first amount that it finds `$7.68`. How do I ignore anything inside brackets so it matches `$84.55` instead?

Appending `(?![^\(]*\))` to the end ignored the line completely, which I don't want.

Comment: Is there only one set of brackets possible? Will there always be a number outside (after) the brackets? Does it matter that your question regex and the regex in your link are different? What about https://regex101.com/r/YXr023/3 ? Instead of trying to make it all non-greedy, just greedy match up to the last $ ... ?

Comment: Yes, only one set of bracket. The description includes ignoring parenthesis part which wasn't working. But yours seems to be working!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler .. except when the amount is a few lines later (bad OCR). Example: http://pastebin.com/ikL3Jvt0

Comment: In other words, You are looking for 2nd occurrence of the desired pattern? Check [Match at every second occurrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589667/match-at-every-second-occurrence) and [How to find 3rd occurrence of a pattern in a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422949/how-to-find-the-3rd-occurrence-of-a-pattern-on-a-line)

Comment: @BehradKhodayar Optionally, not always.

Comment: It is safe to assume that the target is just the number at the end of the line? i.e., `/Total Amount.*\s\$([\d.]+)/`?

Comment: @dawg No, thats the complexity. OCR is terrible, the $amount can be several lines below. I've almost achieved it with `Total Amount.*(?![\(]*\))+?[^\$]*(\$\s?[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{1,})?)(?=\s{2,})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this post will help you out..

**Regex:** `(?<!\()\$[\d\.]+(?!.*?\))`

> **1.** `(?<!\()` negative look behind for `(`
>
> **2.** `\$[\d\.]+` match strings like `$10.1000`
>
> **3.** `(?!.*?\))` does not contain any further `)`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fJWOwo/3)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not extracting $ amounts by itself, I'm checking the label and then looking ahead, so I need to use my regex but just ignore anything inside the brackets

Comment: I'm using this regex on several docs and not just this one, so yours fails on every other. Thanks anyway.