# Return everything before 2nd occurrence in a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, delimiter

I want to return all characters before the 2nd occurrence of the character slash '/' (if any) in PostgreSQL.

Input Column:

```
/apple/orange/banana
/
/mango
/avocado/kiwi
```

Desired Output Column:

```
/apple
/
/mango
/avocado
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get substring from 4th occurence of a character until the end of given string in PSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632213/how-to-get-substring-from-4th-occurence-of-a-character-until-the-end-of-given-st)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `regexp_replace()`:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_replace(col, '^([^/]*/[^/]*)/.*$', '\1')
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd45462391ddf40ac1455aff8bef6d44) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring()` with a regex:

```
select substring(the_column from '(/\w*)')
from the_table
```

Another alternative would be `split_part()`

```
select '/'||split_part(the_column, '/', 2)
from data
```